# Mouse and Keyboard hooking in UWP : Raw input VS KeyEvents VS Global Hook

Tags: c#, c++, hook, uwp, windows-10-universal

I'd like to hook mouse and keyboard in my UWP app, and I'm wondering what is best between [Raw input](https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/windows/desktop/ms645536(v=vs.85).aspx), Global Hook and simple XAML Key events.

Put it simple, I'm developing a UWP application which streams a game (rendered using a cloud server, like nVidia Grid) and I'd like to hook user events (keyboard and mouse) to tell my server the user is moving in a game (for example).

I thought to several approaches:

- Creating a Windows Runtime Component in C++/CX which is consumed by my Universal app in C#. The component would use either Raw Input or Global hook to raise a mouse or keyboard event and send it back to my UWP app.
- Simply use the Key events, like KeyDown and PointerMoved events on a Grid or another UI element and listen to it.

The output will be sent to my server using a socket connection.

What would be the best solution for performance and simplicity?

Comment: You cannot use raw input nor window hooks in UWP.  That makes the choice very simple.

Comment: @HansPassant Effectively! Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems only Key Events are allowed to hook input in UWP.

Comment: Contact Microsoft to expose RawInput properly in the UWP World.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried top hook into the CoreWindow like this?

```
Window.Current.CoreWindow.KeyDown += CoreWindow_KeyDown;
Window.Current.CoreWindow.PointerMoved += CoreWindow_PointerMoved;
```