# How can you capture UWP pointer events on Popups/Tooltips/TeachingTip

Tags: c#, uwp

I'm using UWP's [TeachingTip](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/controls-and-patterns/dialogs-and-flyouts/teaching-tip) and I need to know when the pointer is over the control.

This is how I create and insert the TeachingTip:

```
var teachingTip = new TeachingTip
{
   IsOpen = true,
   Title = "hello",
   Subtitle = "world"
};

var mainPage = (Window.Current.Content as Frame)?.Content as MainPage;
var content = (Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Canvas)mainPage.Content;
content.Children.Add(teachingTip);
```

I tried this but didn't get any event:

```
teachingTip.PointerEntered += TipPointerEntered;
teachingTip.PointerExited += TipPointerExited;
...
```

I also tried this but that didn't make any difference:

```
teachingTip.AddHandler(UIElement.PointerEnteredEvent, new PointerEventHandler(TipPointerEntered), true);
```

Then i read [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/xaml-platform/events-and-routed-events-overview#routed-events-outside-the-visual-tree) this:

> If you want to handle routed events from a Popup or ToolTip, place the handlers on specific UI elements > that are within the Popup or ToolTip and not the Popup or ToolTip elements themselves.

So my best guess is that a TeachingTip behaves the same. But I couldn't figure out how to gain access to the TeachingTip's children.

So I tried a different approach, maybe I could track the pointer once the tip is open and do some hit testing on the control. So I tried this:

```
var mainPage = (Window.Current.Content as Frame)?.Content as MainPage;
mainPage.AddHandler(UIElement.PointerMovedEvent, new PointerEventHandler(PointerMoved), true);  

void PointerMoved(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
{
   var page = (Window.Current.Content as Frame)?.Content as MainPage;
   var currPoint = e.GetCurrentPoint(page);
   var elements = VisualTreeHelper.FindElementsInHostCoordinates(new Windows.Foundation.Point(currPoint.Position.X, currPoint.Position.Y), teachingTip);
   foreach (UIElement element in elements)
   {
      // Eureka! found an element 
   }
}
```

but no eureka... if anyone can help...

Comment: I am just curious, why do you want to know *"when the pointer is over the control"* ? It has clicks and closing [events](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/microsoft.ui.xaml.controls.teachingtip#events), shouldn't that be enough?

Comment: i implemented an auto closing tip after a timeout, and i want to suspend the auto close when the user interacts with the control

Comment: What if you monitor for user inactivity instead? Use [global hooks in uwp](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38830750/1997232) and discard timeout if user moves the mouse anywhere, not only over the tip?

Comment: but that wouldn't make sense from the user's perspective. The timeout should help getting the tip off the screen unless the user is actually interacting with the tip, like aiming to press a button or whatever

Comment: Do you mean you can't find the TeachingTip object or you can't find the child objects of the TeachingTip object?

Comment: I mean child objects like the the title, subtitle, actionbutton, closebutton

Comment: Did it work when you add the event handler on a custom popup control?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eventually I revisited this (a couple of years later...).
The solution is pretty simple, after applying a template you need to get the root element on which you want to register for pointer positions, like this:

```
 protected override void OnApplyTemplate()
    {
        base.OnApplyTemplate();
        var rootGrid = this.GetTemplateChild("ContentRootGrid") as Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Grid;
        if (rootGrid != null)
        {
            rootGrid.PointerEntered += (sender, e) =>
            {
                SetPointerPosition(PointerPosition.Popup);
            };

            rootGrid.PointerExited += (sender, e) =>
            {
                SetPointerPosition(PointerPosition.Page);
            };
        }
    }
```