# How do I access pointer events for WinUi3 TeachingTips?

Tags: c#, winui-3

In my App there are TeachingTips that appear when the pointer hovers over certain controls, and disappear when the pointer leaves those controls (I'll call these the "triggering controls"). This is implemented using the `PointerEntered` and `PointerExited` events of the triggering controls.

The `Target` of the TeachingTips is not the triggering controls, which means that the TeachingTips can sometimes cover the triggering controls. When this happens, the `PointerExited` event of the triggering control is fired, hiding the TeachingTip. This cycles, causing the TeachingTip to flicker.

I've tried two methods to stop this.

First I tried using the pointer events of the TeachingTip to stop it closing if the pointer is over it, however it seems [I need to use the Pointer events of the teaching tip content to achieve this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/xaml-platform/events-and-routed-events-overview#routed-events-outside-the-visual-tree), but cannot figure out how to access the content. I'm setting the content just using the `Title` and `Subtitle` properties of the TeachingTip, and during the `Loaded` event the `Content` property is null. [Edit: this is wrong, see my answer below] I'm not applying a custom template so cannot use the method described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59883086/how-can-you-capture-uwp-pointer-events-on-popups-tooltips-teachingtip).

Next I tried making the teaching tip 'Invisible' to pointer events by setting `IsHitTestVisible` to `false` but that didn't work.

Please can someone let me know how I might achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd misunderstood how templates were being used when I wrote this question, the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59883086/how-can-you-capture-uwp-pointer-events-on-popups-tooltips-teachingtip) did provide a solution:

```
    internal class CustomTeachingTip : TeachingTip
    {
        protected override void OnApplyTemplate()
        {
            base.OnApplyTemplate();
            if (GetTemplateChild("ContentRootGrid") is Grid rootGrid)
            {
                rootGrid.PointerEntered += (o, e) => DoStuff();
                rootGrid.PointerExited += (o, e) => DoOtherStuff();
            }
        }
    }
```